# If Condition To Print “HelloWord”

Tags: python

What should be the “condition” so that the following code snippet prints both HelloWorld!

```
if "condition":
   print "Hello"
else:
   print "World"
```

This can be achieved in C by following code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
     if(!printf("Hello")) 
        printf("Hello"); 
     else
        printf("World"); 
}
```

I'm trying to achieve this in python but can't find a way to print in `if statement`

I wrote a code in python:

```
if (print("Hello")):
    print "World"
else:
    print "World"
```

But the above code is generating a syntax error:

```
if (print("Hello")):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So is there any way this could be achieved in python using `if-else` statement.

Comment: that C snippet doesn't work the way you seem to think it does.

Comment: okay, then how could we accomplish such a thing in python. @Zinki

Comment: Works fine in Python 3, if you add parentheses around the other `print` calls…

Comment: in Python2 `print` is a statement, so you can't use it as condition (works in Python3 though)

Comment: For Python 2, define your own `def hello(): print 'Hello'` and call *that* in the condition…!?

Comment: `def hello()` seems to work perfectly. @deceze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2:

```
def hello():
    print "Hello"

if hello():
    print "BLARGH"
else:
    print "World"
```

Python 3:

```
if print("Hello"):
    print("BLARGH")
else:
    print("World")
```

Why this works in Python 2:

The function `hello()` returns `None` (verify it with `print type(hello())`). To evaluate the `if` the function is called, which prints but returns `None`. `None` is considered as `False` in the `if` so the `else` branch is executed.

Same principle in Python 3, `print()` returns `None` which is considered as `False`. In Python 2 `print` is a keyword so you need to wrap it in a function to get your `None`.

Answer (score -1):

Logically there is no difference between what you are describing and this:

```
if some_condition:
   print "Hello"
   print "World"
```